# how can I keep my spark RDD updated?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am working with apache Spark with cassandra. I am able to create RDDs and get the results. This I am doing using Calliope.

I tried finding a lot about how I can keep my RDD updated without manually refreshing it. I found few examples that can save data in Cassandra using calliope cassandra steraming but I didn't find anything to fetch the data every few seconds and keep my RDD updated. Let me know if anyone has idea about it.

Comment: Would you like to keep your RDD 'in sync' with the stored data in Cassandra? Is that your goal? If that's the case, I think you might need to re-think your approach.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to frequently requery your data using Spark, because it has no choice but to reload the entire table every time (it has no way to know what was updated).  If you want to handle constant updates, you should send your updates into a queue, then use Spark streaming to process them.